# How to decrypt AES-128 encrypted m3u8 TS files

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

we want to decrypt AES-128 encrypted m3u8 TS files. here is our .m3u8 file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="enc.key?wmsAuthSign=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IjdjY2I5ZTAxZGI1YzVkM2IzMWUzMzc1NzQ3MjZjNjYwIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEzMTU4ODM5LCJpc3MiOiJTYWJhIElkZWEgR1NJRyJ9.vvYKPY9tyBnhGGnNtY-XLy_Hz5cyJx5Ma2APVv0g5dk"
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:6.000,
s-1-v1-a1.ts?wmsAuthSign=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IjdjY2I5ZTAxZGI1YzVkM2IzMWUzMzc1NzQ3MjZjNjYwIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEzMTU4ODM5LCJpc3MiOiJTYWJhIElkZWEgR1NJRyJ9.vvYKPY9tyBnhGGnNtY-XLy_Hz5cyJx5Ma2APVv0g5dk
#EXTINF:6.000,
s-2-v1-a1.ts?wmsAuthSign=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IjdjY2I5ZTAxZGI1YzVkM2IzMWUzMzc1NzQ3MjZjNjYwIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEzMTU4ODM5LCJpc3MiOiJTYWJhIElkZWEgR1NJRyJ9.vvYKPY9tyBnhGGnNtY-XLy_Hz5cyJx5Ma2APVv0g5dk
#EXTINF:6.000,
s-3-v1-a1.ts?wmsAuthSign=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IjdjY2I5ZTAxZGI1YzVkM2IzMWUzMzc1NzQ3MjZjNjYwIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEzMTU4ODM5LCJpc3MiOiJTYWJhIElkZWEgR1NJRyJ9.vvYKPY9tyBnhGGnNtY-XLy_Hz5cyJx5Ma2APVv0g5dk
#EXTINF:12.000,
s-4-v1-a1.ts?wmsAuthSign=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IjdjY2I5ZTAxZGI1YzVkM2IzMWUzMzc1NzQ3MjZjNjYwIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEzMTU4ODM5LCJpc3MiOiJTYWJhIElkZWEgR1NJRyJ9.vvYKPY9tyBnhGGnNtY-XLy_Hz5cyJx5Ma2APVv0g5dk
```

we have both `enc.key` file and the server response to `'enc.key'` that is `DVQpuWrxZLd2nCTTxAysIg==`

we are using these C# functions for decryption but we don't know how to find salt or block size ? or basically we are doing it in correct way ?

```
 public static void  DecryptFile(string inputFile, string output,string password)
        {

            byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFile);
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
            byte[] bytesDecrypted = AES_Decrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted, passwordBytes);


            File.Delete(inputFile);


            File.WriteAllBytes(output, bytesDecrypted);
        }


        public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 128;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return decryptedBytes;
        }
```

Comment: `DVQpuWrxZLd2nCTTxAysIg==` looks base-64 encoded to me, so you'll need to decode it rather than use UTF8.GetBytes(). As far as the salt/hash size goes, that's something specific to the format of m3u8 files that's presumably in the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was already a similar quesion here (unable to find it back)

> how to find salt or block size

Look at your `EXT-X-KEY` header. It states `AES-128`, so you will have to use AES-128 (it's the key size, block size is always 128 bit).

According to the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8216/) by default CBC mode with Pkcs7 padding is used.

The section `4.3.2.4.  EXT-X-KEY` further states: `the Initialization Vector (IV) attribute value or the Media Sequence  Number as the IV`

So the IV should be present in the EXT-X-KEY header. If not, the sequence number is used (which is terrible idea for CBC, but this is how it is).

> or basically we are doing it in correct way

Basically it looks ok (except the salt and key). I am not sure what is the encryption key. The encoded response from the server has 16 bites (128 bits) so I'd assume that can be the key (that you will have to find out yourself)

Comment: how can i convert sequence number to IV ?

Comment: @Oli its just binary representation of the number.. like 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000002. However - I use encryption a lot, but not for media files, so I hope it will work for you

Comment: how can i convert 1 or 2 or any number to byte[16] in C# in the shape  of binary representation ?