# How to resolve "hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length" in openssl during file decryption?

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to decrypt a file with

`openssl enc -d -aes128 -in n_1_0_0.ts -out a.ts -K $(hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"' < test.php) -iv 0`

I get this error

```
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
bad decrypt
4618354176:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:
```

*test.php* is a 16Byte file.

Here are the files - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nS5ZI_0HlVPNU6MizvQGVpo_EaxqntfW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "too short" is only a warning, and about the IV. The error means at least one of your key, IV or ciphertext is wrong. In general CBC mode should not be used with zero IV, so that _might_ be the error, but your 'key' is meaningful ASCII text which a proper key should practically never be (maybe once every trillion years in some far-distant galaxy, not here)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'm trying to download a m3u8 file. It doesn't contain an iv but "#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0". Which means iv is 0 right?

Comment: Not in general. This has already been addressed and the concept of StackExchange is that you should look at existing answers; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132088/how-to-decrypt-aes-128-encrypted-m3u8-video-files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769438/how-to-decrypt-aes-128-encrypted-m3u8-ts-files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628791/decrypt-m3u8-playlist-encrypted-with-aes-128-without-iv

Answer (score 0):

As far as warnings are concerned, as mentioned in the comment too, they can be resolved by using the right length for `key` and `iv` strings.

For AES-128, your `key` and `iv` both are expected to be *128-bit* or *16 bytes* long. Thus, corresponding hex string should be *32 characters long*.

I resolved this warning by appending the following code in *python 2.7*:

```
[key].ljust(32, '0')
[iv].ljust(32, '0')
```

Above code will pad `0's` to (placeholder) *key* and *iv* variables.